# Reference request on a sum-of-determinants identity

Tags: reference-request, determinant

Suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3\in\mathbb R^{2\times1}$.  Then
$$
\det[ X_1,X_2] +\det[X_2,X_3] + \det[X_3,X_1] = \det[X_2-X_1,X_3-X_1].
$$
Where are this identity and higher-dimensional versions and their proofs found?

Comment: Du you mean $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$?

Comment: @Raclette : No.  I meant $X_1,X_2,X_3\in\mathbb R^{2\times1}$, so that $[X_1,X_2]$, etc., $\in\mathbb R^{2\times2}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So that the above identity follows from that the determinant is an alternating multilinear function of the columns of the matrix? Add that it maps the identity matrix to the unit in the underlying field, and you have the definition of the determinant.

Comment: @Raclette : Unfortunately I was focused on a geometry question in which this arose and I was distracted by some questions about that and not thinking of _algebra_.  But I think multilinearity will do it.

Comment: Maybe I'll post an answer to this here within a couple of days.